# Mysql query to get max age by section and if two or more has same age return student with smallest id

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table of students with temporary test values like this:

Table **students**

```
+----+-------------+-------+-----------+
| id | section_id  |  age  | name      |
+----+-------------+-------+-----------+
| 1  | 1           | 18    | Justin    |
+----+-------------+-------+-----------+
| 2  | 2           | 14    | Jillian   |
+----+-------------+-------+-----------+
| 3  | 2           | 16    | Cherry    |
+----+-------------+-------+-----------+
| 4  | 3           | 19    | Ronald    |
+----+-------------+-------+-----------+
| 5  | 3           | 21    | Marie     |
+----+-------------+-------+-----------+
| 6  | 3           | 21    | Arthur    |
+----+-------------+-------+-----------+
```

I want to query the table such that I want to get all the maximum ages of each section. However, if two students have the same age, the table produced will return the student with smallest id.

Return:

```
+----+------------+-----+--------+
| id | section_id | age | name   |
+----+------------+-----+--------+
| 1  | 1          | 18  | Justin |
+----+------------+-----+--------+
| 3  | 2          | 16  | Cherry |
+----+------------+-----+--------+
| 5  | 3          | 21  | Marie  |
+----+------------+-----+--------+
```

I tried this query:

```
SELECT ANY_VALUE(id), ANY_VALUE(section_id), MAX(age), ANY_VALUE(name) FROM
(SELECT id, section_id, age, name FROM students ORDER BY id) as X
GROUP BY section_id
```

Unfortunately, there are instances that id does not match the age and name.

I have on my end:

```
sql_mode = only_full_group_by
```

and I don't have a privilege to edit that, hence the any_value function but I have no idea how to use it.

Comment: It's good practice to store a person's date of birth, rather than their age, because the date of birth doesn't change, where age changes every year.

Comment: good point. It could be that this is a derived table... and actually very different from what I'm having now. Its just for demonstration... thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do what you want.

It starts by finding the maximum age per section (including duplicates).
Then it joins those results with the minimum id per section (to eliminate duplicates).
And finally, select all fields for the matching id and section combinations.

```
SELECT s3.*
FROM students s3
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT MIN(s2.id) AS id, s2.section_id
    FROM students s2
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT s1.section_id, MAX(s1.age) AS age
        FROM students s1
        GROUP BY s1.section_id  
    ) s1 USING (section_id, age)
    GROUP BY s2.section_id
) s2 USING (id, section_id);
```

Working SQL fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aezgAYM6A5KnXykceB7At1/0

Answer (score 1):

I would simply use a correlated subquery:

```
select s.*
from students s
where s.id = (select s2.id
              from students s2
              where s2.section_id = s.section_id
              order by s2.age desc, s2.id asc
              limit 1
             );
```

This is pretty much the simplest way to express the logic.  And with an index on `students(section, age, id)`, it should be the most performant as well.

Comment: thanks for another answer. Correlated subquery is definitely another area I'm not familiar with...